# How to Post a photo on other's Timeline/Page from Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

We are developing a Android App which invloves Facebook , We need to post a photo on A Page from our app , The Page is ours and has all permissions , I read a post that Facebook has Removed this Functionality of posting on others timeline and Pages , but I read this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

which says it is possible , and I dont know to use it , can you plz brief me about this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
 try{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");//title 
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");//caption 
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("picture", strImageUrl);
    params.putString("to", "TARGET Facebook USER ID");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(InviteParticipantsActivity.this,
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(null)
            .build();
        feedDialog.show();
 }
 catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```